# Visualforce Remote Objects - Context incomplete - authorization not provided

Tags: visualforce, remote-action, remote-objects

I am using Visualforce Remote objects for a simple query to get a value from a custom object in **Guest-user** context inside the community and also same thing happens if run the vf page using "/apex/[vfpagename]".

**Error**

> Visualforce Remoting: Context incomplete - authorization not provided

**Code**

```
<!-- Remote Objects definition of jobs to get Job term -->
    <apex:remoteObjects >
        <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Job__c" jsShorthand="jobs" fields="Id, JobTerm__c" />
    </apex:remoteObjects>
    <!-- JavaScript to make Remote Objects calls -->
    <script>
        var fetchJobTerm = function(){
            // Create a new Remote Object
            var job = new SObjectModel.jobs();
            // Use the Remote Object to query for jobterm
            job.retrieve({where: {Id: {eq: '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.jobId}' }}}, function(err, records, event){
                if(err) {
                    alert(err.message);
                }
                else {
                    var clsJobTerm = document.getElementById("jobTerm");
                    records.forEach(function(record) {
                        var jobTerm = record.get("JobTerm__c");
                        alert("JobTerm is:" + jobTerm);
                        //clsJobTerm = jobTerm;
                    });
                }
            });
        };
        
        window.onload = function() {
            fetchJobTerm();
        };
    </script>
```

[**Spring'21 - Security Update**](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_vf_js_remoting_security_ru.htm&type=5&release=234))

Has already been applied to the sandbox and I honestly don't see a way around it.

Comment: Is that an error? Or just a warning message?

Comment: @kurunve - I get that error in the console.

Comment: After I have applied the update, this approach stop working. I have also provided the JavaScript as static resource, but it did not work